# SMO Restoring Took Forever

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, smo, database-backups, database-restore

I use this SMO to restore a backup:

```
        Server myServer = new Server(@"PC-1\Instance1");
        Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
        restoreDB.Database = "Sample";
        restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        restoreDB.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\Sample.bak", DeviceType.File);
        restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        restoreDB.NoRecovery = true;
        restoreDB.SqlRestore(myServer);
```

But when I open SSMS the restoring took forever

[image]

I use this to backup database and able to backup the database

```
            Server myServer = new Server(@"PC-1\Instance1");
            Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
            bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            bkpDBFull.Database = "Sample";
            bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\Sample.bak", DeviceType.File);
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Sample";
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Sample";
            bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);
            bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;
            bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following line in your code:

```
restoreDB.NoRecovery = true;
```

Hence the database will stay showing as restoring in SSMS forever until you run

```
RESTORE DATABASE [sample] WITH RECOVERY
```

Or its SMO equivalent, I'm not sure exactly what that would be.